# ogr2ogr clip one GeoJSON with another

Tags: ogr2ogr, bash

I'm trying to clip the NYC streets layer using a NYC borough polygon layer. This works:

`ogr2ogr -clpsrc manhattan-borough.geojson manhattan-streets.geojson nycStreetCenterline-simplified.geojson -progress`

The problem is the file that it produces apparently has three layers like a CAD file? This is what it looks like in QGIS:
[image]

And I can't get a preview of it in VSCode so it's acting like a corrupted file. Is there a flag/feature in my command that I'm missing to produce a single GeoJSON of the clipped Manhattan streets?

Comment: Before clipping manhattan-streets layer probably contains only linestrings but clipping process is cutting the original geometries. Sometimes the result from the intersection is just a single point, sometimes line is cut into two or more unconnected pieces which are stored as GeometryCollection. QGIS can handle only one geometry type on a single layer and therefore you get three layers from the one GeoJSON file that ogr2ogr creates.

Comment: is there a way to force just a LineString output to your knowledge?

Comment: Maybe other types of geometries are skipped if you add `-nlt linestring` into your command, perhaps with `-skipfailures`.